# toggle class on ul to change font

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm very new to javascript & jQuery and I'm having trouble with toggling a class when a button is clicked. The desired output is to have the user add items as they click a button. That works fine. However when they want to `check` an item off their list, I can't get the font to change to be strike-through when the user clicks the button that is inside the `<li>`.

I think I'm close but there's something amiss.
Any help is appreciated.

CODE:

```
function checkItem(element) {
    // toggles the class shopping-item__checked when button inside the parent <li> is clicked
    element.parent('li').toggleClass('.shopping-item__checked');
    console.log(element);
}

// Event listeners
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("ready!");
    $('#js-shopping-list-form').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        addItem(state, $('#shopping-list-entry').val());
        renderList(state, $('.shopping-list'));
    });
    $('ul.shopping-list > li').click(checkItem($(this).closest('shopping-item')));
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <form id="js-shopping-list-form">
        <label for="shopping-list-entry">Add an item</label>
        <input type="text" name="shopping-list-entry" id="shopping-list-entry" placeholder="e.g., broccoli">
        <button type="submit">Add item</button>
    </form>
    <ul class="shopping-list">
        <li>
            <span class="shopping-item">apples</span>
            <div class="shopping-item-controls">
                <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
                    <span class="button-label">check</span>
                </button>
                <button class="shopping-item-delete">
                    <span class="button-label">delete</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </li>
```

Comment: Something like:

$('.shopping-item-delete').click(function(e) {

    $(this).parent().find('.shopping-item').addClass('class-that-make-a-strike-through');

} );

Answer (score 0):

remove the '.' from the toggleclass,

```
function checkItem(element) {
    // toggles the class shopping-item__checked when button inside the parent <li> is clicked
    element.parent('li').toggleClass('shopping-item__checked');
    console.log(element);
}
```

also u can try the following as alternative

```
function checkItem(element) {
    // toggles the class shopping-item__checked when button inside the parent <li> is clicked
    if(element.parent('li').hasClass('shopping-item__checked')){
        element.parent('li').removeClass('shopping-item__checked');
    }else{
        element.parent('li').addClass('shopping-item__checked');
    }
    console.log(element);
}
```

Comment: Why would anyone want to use the if/else version? (Other than in cases where more things need to happen inside the if or the else...)

Comment: i mentioned it as alternative. if the toggleclass is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding event handlers the wrong way.

```
$('ul.shopping-list > li').click(checkItem($(this).closest('shopping-item')));
```

You need to pass the event information in the following manner.

```
function checkItem(event) {
    //event information is passed. target contains the target element on which the event was fired. in this case the check button
    var element = $(event.target);
    // toggles the class shopping-item__checked when button inside the parent <li> is clicked
    //element.parent('li').toggleClass('.shopping-item__checked');
    element.closest('li').find('span.shopping-item').css('text-decoration','line-through');
    console.log(element);
}

// Event listeners
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("ready!");
    $('#js-shopping-list-form').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        addItem(state, $('#shopping-list-entry').val());
        renderList(state, $('.shopping-list'));
    });
    //bind each check button with the check item function
    $('ul.shopping-list > li > div.shopping-item-controls > button.shopping-item-toggle').on('click', {event_data:this}, checkItem);
});
```

and modify your html to remove the span inside the button, coz it it's unecessary.

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <form id="js-shopping-list-form">
        <label for="shopping-list-entry">Add an item</label>
        <input type="text" name="shopping-list-entry" id="shopping-list-entry" placeholder="e.g., broccoli">
        <button type="submit">Add item</button>
    </form>
    <ul class="shopping-list">
        <li>
            <span class="shopping-item">apples</span>
            <div class="shopping-item-controls">
                <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
                    <!--<span class="button-label">check</span>-->
                    <!-- recommend not to use the span, since you will not be able to capture click event of button -->
                    check
                </button>
                <button class="shopping-item-delete">
                    <span class="button-label">delete</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </li>
```

the `.closest()` method finds the closest matching ancestor, while the `.find()` method finds the closest matching child.

https://coderwall.com/p/wxjljq/jquery-find-and-closest-are-your-best-friends

Answer (score 0):

First things first you are adding the callback function wrong for the jQuery click event.

```
$('ul.shopping-list > li').click(checkItem($(this).closest('shopping-item')));
```

You are actually passing in `undefined` as a callback function because you are calling `checkItem()` right away and that function returns nothing. So everytime you click on the li elements they do nothing.

Lets fix that by just adding in the function name without any paranthesis. So we are not calling it we are just passing it through as a parameter.

```
$('ul.shopping-list > li .shopping-item-toggle').click(checkItem);
```

I have also targeted the check button for the click in this example. Now everytime the button is clicked it will call checkItem and pass in an event object like so: `checkItem(event);`

Looking at your checkItem function it is expecting an element to be passed through, well lets change that part:

```
function checkItem(event) {
    // toggles the class shopping-item__checked when button inside the parent <li> is clicked
    $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('shopping-item__checked');
    console.log(this);
}
```

I changed a few things here. I changed the parameter name from element to event and I changed `element.parent('li').blah.blah` to `$(this).closest('li').blah.blah`

`this` is going to represent the element clicked and I wrap it in a jquery selector so I can chain some stuff to it like the closest and toggleClass methods.

Now I noticed that this is going to work for the first element but its not going to work for elements that you add later. This is because you would have to add a click event to the new list item everytime you call `addItem`. There is an easier way to do that and it would require us to modify how we add the click event in the first place.

```
$('ul.shopping-list').on('click', 'li .shopping-item-toggle', checkItem);
```

This technique that we are using now is called Event Delagation. Now I am actually adding the click event on the entire shopping list and its going fire on all `li .shopping-item-toggle` items that were clicked inside the shopping list. This means the elements don't yet need to be added at this point for them to have a click event work on it. They can be added later and it will still work. Now when you add new items you can click on them and they will have the click event fire.